# Turn off html tags in PHP errors

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm running a PHP script from the command line. Is it possible to disable HTML tags in error message?

For example, when an error occurs, instead of outputting like:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Exception'
```

the error is output like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'
```

Comment: i have used this and it is working fine for me. ini_set('html_errors', false);

Answer (score 1):

Add this line towards the top of the script:

```
ini_set('html_errors', false);
```